# How we can select the value of an <option> in <select> by using text in <option>text<option>

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

How we can select the value of an `<option>` in `<select>` by using 'text' in

`<option value="123">text<option>`

Here is the xpath,by using this i'm able to check that there is a option in `<select>` witch contains '`text`'

> string xpath = "//*[contains(@name,
>   'selectname')]/option[contains(translate(text(), "
>            + "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'text')]";

Here is the html

```
<select name="selectname">
<option value="`123`">text</option>
<option value="456">text</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the value `123` by using same xpath which first check that there is a option witch contains some ie 'text' and get the value ie '123'.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var values = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@name='selectname']/option")
                .Where(o => o.InnerText=="text")
                .Select(o => o.Attributes["value"].Value)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML Agility pack you should be able to use the InnerHTML

Comment: InnerHTML returns `text` by using above xpath.